# Windows CE project with libraries problem

Tags: debugging, windows-ce, libraries

I am developing a Windows CE application which uses some libraries provided by other parts of our company.

When I deploy my application on "My Computer" (.NET compact application running on standard PC), everything works, but when I deploy to the device, the application hangs when trying to use methods from the library. The system also hangs. My Visual Studio 2008 sometime hangs, but sometime throws an exception "TypeLoadException: Could not load type from assembly Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=nu".

I couldn't include .NET Compact framework 3.5 because the image wouldn't compile, so I am using version 2.0. I use Visual Studio 2008 with deploy .NET framework option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably the problem is with version of the library you are using. Please cross check it.

Hope this [link](http://forums.asp.net/t/1182823.aspx) will help you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit confused.

First of all, what are the libraries "provided by other parts of [y]our company" build against?  Are they Compact Framework assemblies (they must be)?  What version of the Framework were they build against?  Reflector can tell you this if you don't know.

Second, why can't you compile it with 3.5?  What sort of errors are you seeing?  The code should be 100% forward compatible, so if it won't build, there's a red flag going up.

Lastly, what version of the CF is installed on the target hardware?  FOr example, are you trying to push a CF 2.0 app to a device with CF 3.5 already installed?  If so, do you have an app.config file that provides the framework compatibility options so it knows it can run your assembly?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that libraries were compiled with for 3.5 target framework, and the application which uses them form 2.0 framework. In that case, 3.5 framework wasn't depoloyed and application would stop working as soon as call to the library methods was made.